# Given $ A $ find $ B $ so that $ [ A \: B ] [ A \: B ] ^ { \mathrm T } $ is the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $ A $ ($ 4 \times 2 $ matrix) I want to find $ B $ ($ 4 \times 2 $ matrix) such that when you append both in a single $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix $ [ A \: B ] $ the following relationship will hold:
$$
[ A \: B ] [ A \: B ] ^ { \mathrm T } = I
$$

**Edit context:**
I am going through a paper on unambiguous state discrimination where a process has been outlined for finding optimal discrimination matrices. This is the paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4557236. In section (3) the paper uses the matrix I have called $ B $ but does not however tell how to get the matrix. $ A $ is made up of the null space vectors of a rank $ 2 $ matrix in a $ 4 $-dimensional Hilbert space. $ A $ is also real.

Comment: Please provide some context for this question. Where did you find the question? Is there a specific $A$ that matters to you? Why is this question important to you or the larger community? Check out [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details on community standards for questions.

Comment: $AB$ is not well defined as $A$ and $B$ are not comformable.

Comment: @TheoBendit I hope this is sufficient context. If not please let me know how to improve the question

Comment: @Eldorado The matrices are being **appended**, not multiplied

Comment: @LordBallom Yep, that's some good context! +1. Welcome to MSE by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot access the paper you linked. However, I suspect that "null space vectors" refer to an orthonormal basis for the nullspace.

If this is the case, then the columns of $A$ are orthonormal, and it follows that the matrix $M = [A\ \ B]$ will satisfy $MM^T = I$ if and only if $M^TM = I$, which holds if and only all columns of $M$ are orthonormal. Thus, a satisfactory matrix $B$ can be build from the nullspace vectors of $A^T$.

Comment: Orthonormalise the columns of A by Gram Schmid and choose B to be any two orthonormal vectors which form an orthonormal collection along with columns of A. You are done.

Comment: @Lawrence First, as I state in my answer, it seems from context that the columns of $A$ are already orthonormal. Second, how exactly do you "find any two orthonormal vectors which form an orthonormal collection along with the columns of $A$"? The typical pencil and paper approach is to find a basis for the nullspace and then go through the Gram Schmidt procedure *again*, so it seems to me that you are leaving off an important part of the process there

Comment: @LawrenceMano Finally, while the Gram-Schmidt process is fine for a pencil and paper approach, it is numerically unstable and therefore avoided in the context of numerical linear algebra. Built-in computer methods typically use [Householder or Givens transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Householder_reflections) instead.

Comment: I agree to your knowledgeable remark.